# JMS Distribution Queue in Weblogic Cluster

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x

I have a Weblogic cluster ( with 1 Admin & 4 managed servers). weblogic 10.3.5 version
In JMS Queue distribution I have the problem something like below

When the 4th Managed server ( Added Recently) started then the Distribution Queue sending all the requests to 4th Server only & remaining 3 managed servers not doing anything

When 4th Server is OFF, then the remaining 3 managed servers (Server1,2,3) are getting equal load and the distribution happening perfectly ..

I checked the complete Queues and all the configurations seems to be correct.

What could be the possible causes? Have you ever faced this kind of problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you remember to add the 4th server to a cluster inside weblogic with the other 3?

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable (uncheck) "server affinity" from the connection factory -> load balancing
2. Make sure all the four servers are in cluster

Then restart all the servers (including Admin) and then try again.